# "No data - zero rows fetched, selected, or processed" on Select Query with Group By clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a strange MySql Warning message when executing the following query :

```
  SELECT COURRIER.ID AS ID,
   COURRIER.TYPE AS TYPE,
   COURRIER.NUMERO_COURRIER AS NUMERO_COURRIER,
   COURRIER.ETAT AS ETAT,
   COURRIER.ETAT_TRI AS ETAT_TRI,
   COURRIER.DATE_DEBUT_ETAT AS DATE_DEBUT_ETAT,
   COURRIER.LU AS LU,
   COURRIER.ALERTE AS ALERTE,
   COURRIER.SIGNALE AS SIGNALE,
   COURRIER.CONFIDENTIEL AS CONFIDENTIEL,
   COURRIER.BROUILLON AS BROUILLON,
   COURRIER.TYPE_RETOUR AS TYPE_RETOUR,
   COURRIER.REPONSE_OBLIGATOIRE AS REPONSE_OBLIGATOIRE,
   COURRIER.URGENCE AS URGENCE,
   COURRIER.URGENCE_DESCRIPTION AS URGENCE_DESCRIPTION,
   COURRIER.DATE_ENREGISTREMENT AS DATE_ENREGISTREMENT,
   COURRIER.DATE_RECEPTION AS DATE_RECEPTION,
   COURRIER.DATE_REPONSE_ATTENDUE AS DATE_REPONSE_ATTENDUE,
   COURRIER.DATE_BONNE_RECEPTION_ATTENDUE AS DATE_BONNE_RECEPTION_ATTENDUE,
   COURRIER.DATE_DERNIERE_ACTION AS DATE_DERNIERE_ACTION,
   COURRIER.ACCUSE_RECEPTION_INITIE AS ACCUSE_RECEPTION_INITIE,
   COURRIER.REPONSE_INITIE AS REPONSE_INITIE,       

   COURRIER.DATE_DEBUT_DERNIERE_AFFECTATION AS DATE_DEBUT_DERNIERE_AFFECTATION,
   COURRIER.DOCUMENT_EN_SIGNATURE AS DOCUMENT_EN_SIGNATURE,
   COURRIER.ID_ORGANISME AS ID_ORGANISME,
   GET_TIERS_NOM_COMPLET(COURRIER.ID_TIERS) AS TIERS,
   COURRIER.ID_THEME AS ID_THEME,
   GET_THEME_NOM(COURRIER.ID_THEME) AS THEME_NOM,
   COURRIER.OBJET AS OBJET,
   SERVICE_ACTUEL.ID AS ID_SERVICE_ACTUEL,
   SERVICE_ACTUEL.NOM_COURT AS NOM_COURT_SERVICE_ACTUEL,
   SERVICE_ACTUEL.NOM AS NOM_SERVICE_ACTUEL,
   RESPONSABLE.ID AS ID_RESPONSABLE,
   RESPONSABLE.PRENOM AS PRENOM_RESPONSABLE,
   RESPONSABLE.NOM AS NOM_RESPONSABLE,
   RESPONSABLE.ID_SERVICE AS ID_SERVICE_RESPONSABLE,
   GET_SERVICE_RESPONSABLE_NOM(RESPONSABLE.ID_SERVICE,1) AS     NOM_COURT_SERVICE_RESPONSABLE,
   GET_SERVICE_RESPONSABLE_NOM(RESPONSABLE.ID_SERVICE,0) AS NOM_SERVICE_RESPONSABLE,
   GET_ID_PIECE_JOINTE(COURRIER.ID_FICHIER_PRINCIPAL) AS ID_PIECE_JOINTE_PRINCIPALE,
   COURRIER.NUMERO_COURRIER AS NUMERO_COURRIER_PROPRIETAIRE,
   COURRIER.ID AS ID_RELATION
FROM COURRIER       
  INNER JOIN SERVICE SERVICE_ACTUEL on SERVICE_ACTUEL.ID = COURRIER.ID_SERVICE_ACTUEL
  LEFT JOIN UTILISATEUR RESPONSABLE on RESPONSABLE.ID = COURRIER.ID_RESPONSABLE
  GROUP BY  COURRIER.ID
```

The warning message is :

"No data - zero rows fetched, selected, or processed"

When i delete the GROUP BY clause .. the warning message dissapears.

Any idea ?

Comment: Does one of your UDFs use a cursor by any chance?

Comment: It might be because you are pulling an enormous number of columns, with joins, then telling it to group the results on only ONE column.  There is probably no way it will resolve unique records so they CAN be grouped.

Comment: @durbnpoisn The error that OP is getting is specific to stored procedures, so it's one of his stored procs that's actually generating the error.

Comment: I see no evidence that this is a stored procedure.  Unless I'm totally missing something.

Comment: You are missing something. He is calling his own stored procedures within the query, e.g. `GET_TIERS_NOM_COMPLET(COURRIER.ID_TIERS) AS TIERS` or `GET_THEME_NOM(COURRIER.ID_THEME) AS THEME_NOM`

Comment: Of course we cannot know what your custom functions do, so I'll just note that in the absence of any obvious aggregating functions, your use of a GROUP BY clause would appear to be inappropriate.

Comment: i use the group by clause to remove duplicate rows ( the last left join may generate multiple rows ) ... when i remove the call to the used stored procedures .. i get no warnings .. the problem is in the stored procedures

Comment: ...which we know nothing about!

Comment: yeap ... bit i didn't knew that this warning message is related to stored procedures ... now i know

Answer (score 0):

It would seem like you should remove the group by and just do a

SELECT DISTINCT COURRIER.ID AS ID,
   COURRIER.TYPE AS TYPE,
...

Effectively the DISTINCT is doing a group by all columns.  I don't have MySQL on the computer I'm at, but at least in SQL server if I try to do something like the query you have, I get

Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column (column name) is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.